# change primeng p-chart height in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, chart.js

I would change the height of the y axis or the height of the chart.

Here's my data and options:

```
this.data = {
        labels: ['SAF/TGA'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'SAF/TGA',
                backgroundColor: '#9CBB65',
                borderColor: '#72242',
                data: [28],
            }
        ],
  }

        this.options = {
      legend: {
          display: false
      },
      responsive: false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,

      scales: {
          yAxes: [{
              display: true,
              barThickness: 5,
              gridLines: {
                  display: true,
                  offsetGridLines: false,
                  drawBorder: true


              },
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 500


              }

          }],
          xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                  display: false,
                  offsetGridLines: false,
                  drawBorder: false
              }
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  display: false,
                  suggestedMax: 100,
                  max: 100,
              }
          }]
      },

  }
```

then I call the component and define a height

```
<p-chart type="horizontalBar" [data]="data" [options]="options" width="10px" height="5px" >
</p-chart>
```

I have tried with multiple possibilities :

```
width="10px" height="5px"
or
[width]="10px" [height]="5px"
or 
width="10" height="5"
...
```

no one works . I don't know how to decrease the height of my chart.

[image: example]

**UPDATE :** when I use the inspector and modify the `class="chartjs-render-monitor"`css, the height changes

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem : [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uIGxxEzu2J2Fs8pTVUmv?p=preview) Can you share your data please ?

Comment: I have added my data

Comment: Check with my Plunker what could be the differences between your code and mine...